# Fetching firestore doc id with where condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch Firestore doc id using this command below:

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('cities').where('name', '==', 'JALANDHAR').get();
console.log(ref);
```

In console, it shows this:

[image]

I want to fetch the `ID` in image

I am trying like this - `const docRefId = ref.docs[0].id` but it is giving error - `Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'Promise<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>>`

### Edit 1

Trying with query snapshot like this:

`const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('cities').where('name', '==', 'JALANDHAR').get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  const docRefId = ref.docs[0].id;
})`

Comment: `get()` doesn't return a reference.  The error message is telling you that it returns a promise that will resolve with a QuerySnapshot object.  You should deal with it like you would any other promise.  You will have to then iterate the documents in the QuerySnapshot to find the data in the documents.  I suggest reviewing the documentation again on Firstore queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

Comment: I am doing something wrong, updated question, please advise further

Comment: Why are simple questions like this not answered ?